# Print string up to a certain word - Java

Tags: java, string, printing

I was wondering in Java how I could print a string until it reaches the word "quit" in that string and then instantly stop printing at that point. For instance if the string value was:

"Hi there this is a random string quit this should not be printed"

All that should be printed is "Hi there this is a random string".

I was trying something like this, but I believe it to be wrong.

```
if ( input.indexOf( "quit" ) > -1 ) 

    {

    //code to stop printing here
    }
```

Comment: If it is a normal string, just create a substring until that point :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of thinking about the problem as "how to *stop* printing" (because once you start printing something in Java it's pretty hard to stop it), think about it in terms of "How can I print only the words up to a certain point?" For example:

```
int quit_position = input.indexOf("quit");
if (quit_position >= 0) {
    System.out.println(input.substring(0, quit_position));
} else {
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the efficient, straightforward implementation over the one-liner ;)

Answer (score 3):

*Looks like homework, so this answer is in homework style. :-)*

You're on the right track.

Save the value of that indexOf to an integer.

Then it's like you have a finger pointing at the right spot - ie, at the end of the substring you really want to print.

That's a hint anyway...

EDIT: Looks like people are giving it to you anyway. But here are some more thoughts:

1. You might want to think about upper and lower case as well.
2. Also consider what you are going to do if 'quit' is not there.
3. Also the solutions here don't strictly solve your problem - they'll print unnecessary spaces too, after the last word ends, before 'quit' starts. If that is a problem you consider [String Tokenization](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236) or an adapation of the `replaceAll` solution above to cover for leading whitespace into `quit'.

Comment: it's 50/50 homework. I'm working on a project for my cs101 class and this is a small part of it, and thanks I totally understood what you were saying.

Comment: @Twisterz If this helped you find a solution you should reward azhrei and Greg by upvoting their answers.

Answer (score 2):

This has a one-line solution:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("quit.*", ""));
```

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regex to match, which I've specified to be "the literal 'quit' and everything following", which is to be replaced by a blank `""` (ie effectively deleted) from the returned String

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution, but dislike the fact that it _destroys_ the original String. It may be the case that the text after `quit` is needed for other things besides printing. That may also not be the case at all, just pointing it out.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It **doesn't destroy the original String**: `replaceAll()` returns a **new** String. Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)!

Comment: for some reason I thought that `replaceAll()` was an in-place operation that overwrote the String object it was called on. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind trailing spaces in your string

```
int index = input.indexOf("quit");
if (index == -1) index = input.length();
return input.substring(0, index);
```